# Push/ animate to the top if you receive any new chat message or Items in a Listview with firestore

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I animate to top of the ListView, if I receive any new data from firestore , I know the code which animates or pushes to the bottom  but where should I place it specifically to ensure that this operation works, whenever there's change in data.?

This is my ListView wrapped with a StreamBuilder :

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: commentsStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }

          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            child: snapshot.data.documents.length != 0
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    reverse: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CommentsTile(
                        message: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["message"],
                        isAuthor: int.parse(snapshot
                                    .data.documents[index].data["isAuthor"]
                                    .toString()
                                    .trim()) ==
                                0
                            ? false
                            : true,
                        value: int.parse(snapshot
                            .data.documents[index].data["isAuthor"]
                            .toString()
                            .trim()),
                        name: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["username"],
                        date: formatDate(
                            snapshot.data.documents[index].data["time"]),
                      );
                    })
                : Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "No comments",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  ),
          );
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onData` parameter of the `.listen` method for streams. Put any code you need to run when the `Stream` updates in `onData`.

The `.listen` call should be done in the `initState` method if the surrounding widget is stateful.

See [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) for more information on the `listen` method.

**Edit:**

To implement in your code add

```
commentsStream.listen(() {
  onReloadNewChat();
});
```

to your `initState` method immediately following

```
setState(() {
  commentsStream = value
});
```

Comment: Can you kindly show me an example with my existing code. Thanks

Comment: @IdrisStack You would need to provide more code that includes how you "animates or pushes to the bottom".

Comment: Ok Christopher, for simplicity I have attached whole class to this link :

https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/34f345c45a60df65bdffcf9c7e18e591

Comment: On line 130 and 259, it's where I do the animation from

Comment: @IdrisStack Just made an edit. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This is what I implemented : ```databaseMethods
        .getCommentsPerArticle(articleId: widget.articleId)
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        commentsStream = value;
      });

      commentsStream.listen((v) {
        onReloadNewChat();
      });

    });```, but the list doesn't load I get the error below

Comment: error I get ```[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 110 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.```

Comment: It happens when I load the page, tried to make it await but also wasn't successful

Comment: @IdrisStack Add a boolean condition that is set in the `ListView` `builder` and is checked by the callback passed to the `listen` method.

Comment: Am still a nwebie in flutter :), can kindly hint please on the boolean

Comment: Do I insert the logic on the controller of the Listview builder? maybe kindly comment the code on the gist link please. :)

Comment: @IdrisStack Wrap `onReloadNewChat()` with an if statement that checks a `bool`. Set this `bool` following the creation of the `ListView` in the build method.